# Convert a single Pandas column to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

In my dataframe, I set the index of each column to 'Time' and then did `frame = frame.astype(float)` to convert all the the other data to floats. However, I now need the default indices (0, 1, 2, etc) but I still want to set the 'Time' column to a date time format. I've tried a few different ways of doing this, they either work but mess up the time (says its 1970 instead of 2021) or they result in `TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype float64`

This is similar to the dataframe I want (but with the times messed up):

```
                          Time      Open      High       Low     Close
0   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185760  57141.92  57157.16  57141.92  57147.00
1   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185820  57145.48  57149.15  57124.62  57139.75
2   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185880  57126.75  57173.11  57126.74  57142.20
3   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185940  57163.42  57163.42  57079.10  57135.31
4   1970-01-01 00:27:18.186000  57084.42  57110.00  57084.42  57092.95
```

I've tried changing the format of the 'Time' column with:

```
frame['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Time'])
```

And

```
frame['Time'] = frame['Time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

And I have also tried changing the types of the other columns in a similar way

```
frame[['Open','High','Low','Close']] = frame[['Open','High','Low','Close']].apply(frame.astype(float))
```

And I tried this before and after applying `pd.to_datetime`

---

**EDIT**

Going to give some more information because I haven't been specific enough. The code below retrieves data from an API and puts it into a DataFrame. The response from the API is a list of lists, with each sublist containing 10 elements (I think, can't remember now). I only want the data up to 'Close'.

```
def get_historical_futures_data(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.futures_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback+' min ago UTC'))
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:5]
    frame.columns = ['Time','Open','High','Low','Close']
    frame = frame.set_index('Time')
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    print(frame)
    frames.append(frame)
```

```
                         Open      High       Low     Close
Time                                                       
2021-11-29 14:27:00  57220.49  57220.50  57185.95  57190.01
2021-11-29 14:28:00  57190.00  57209.21  57161.74  57177.28
2021-11-29 14:29:00  57177.28  57182.61  57160.26  57164.46
2021-11-29 14:30:00  57164.46  57186.99  57154.32  57155.99
2021-11-29 14:31:00  57156.00  57179.74  57154.33  57179.74
```

Above is the code (and its output), I had previously, however, in another part of my code, I have realised that it is much easier for me to keep the row index numbers, so I do not want to make 'Time' the index of each row. Instead, I want the index of each row to remain, and then the rest of the data frame to come after, similar to this:

```
                          Time      Open      High       Low     Close
0   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185760  57141.92  57157.16  57141.92  57147.00
1   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185820  57145.48  57149.15  57124.62  57139.75
2   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185880  57126.75  57173.11  57126.74  57142.20
3   1970-01-01 00:27:18.185940  57163.42  57163.42  57079.10  57135.31
4   1970-01-01 00:27:18.186000  57084.42  57110.00  57084.42  57092.95
```

My issue is, that I am unable to make the 'Time' column into a DateTime type as well as make the other columns (Open, High, Low, Close) into float type. I either get errors about type casting, or the Time column gets messed up and says 1970 instead of 2021.

How do I make every column (EXCEPT FOR TIME) float type, and make the Time column DateTime type?

Comment: not sure I understand the issue. Did you run a "wrong" command and want to "cancel"? Can't your restart your script/notebook? Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue (provide input data)?

Comment: Can't you just `frame.reset_index()`, this should give you the time index as a column and and a new index from 0 to n ?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here - are you saying that you have a "time" column in your `DataFrame` that contains "floating point numbers"? Or are you saying that your "time" column has "datetime like entries" and you are unable to convert it to the right datetime values?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this issue might be happening because the format is not easy to find by pandas. Perhaps you can try using `infer_datetime_format=True` to enhance the formats being detected.

Kindly try:

```
frame['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Time'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

This outputs

```
                        Time
0 1970-01-01 00:27:18.185760
1 1970-01-01 00:27:18.185820
2 1970-01-01 00:27:18.185880
```

And by using `df.info()` we can check it's an actual datetime format:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Time    3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 152.0 bytes
None
```

This is the sample data used for this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['1970-01-01 00:27:18.185760',
                           '1970-01-01 00:27:18.185820',
                           '1970-01-01 00:27:18.185880']})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution gives me this error: 
```
raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")
pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. My times were being changed from the year 2021 to 1970 because I wasn't specifying that the unit was in milliseconds. My code is very similar to what I had initially, and the solution is actually really simple:

```
def get_historical_futures_data(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.futures_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback+' min ago UTC'))
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:5]
    frame.columns = ['Time','Open','High','Low','Close']
    frame['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Time'], unit='ms')
    frame[['Open','High','Low','Close']] = frame[['Open','High','Low','Close']].astype(float)
    print(frame)
    frames.append(frame)
```

Output is:

```
                  Time      Open      High       Low     Close
0   2021-11-29 19:17:00  58388.41  58401.33  58357.30  58359.75
1   2021-11-29 19:18:00  58359.74  58365.33  58270.00  58290.95
2   2021-11-29 19:19:00  58290.95  58291.80  58173.28  58188.67
3   2021-11-29 19:20:00  58188.68  58317.02  58174.30  58308.70
4   2021-11-29 19:21:00  58309.32  58365.75  58309.31  58330.55
```